# How to display a loading gif image in iphone application while uiwebview content loads

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a uiwebview in my iphone application. I want to show a loading gif image which is located in my application , until  complete contents of my uiwebview loads . Can anybody suggest a method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [detailed post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/showing-message-over-iphone-keyboard.html), including sample code, regarding usage of UIActivityIndicatorView to overlay a loading view over different types of subviews.

Comment: I have a doubt. I tried this method. It works fine when UIwebview loads. But when it go to next page in same Webview , loading image not showing....

I used these functions 

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
}


and 
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
}
Can u answer me ?